Error finding printers: MissingPluginException
flutter: Error finding printers: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listDevices on channel usb_serial)
why this error ?
i write code test show devices
Future<void> _findPrinters() async {
    try {
      List<UsbDevice> devices = await UsbSerial.listDevices();
     print("devices ${devices.length}");
     print("devices ${devices}");
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error finding printers: $e');
    }
  }

